# How do i convert a Set into 2D array in java?

Tags: java, collections

So, i have a Set, where each instance has four fields.
I want to convert it to Array[i][j], where each [j] row would represent an instance.

Edit:
Ok. Sorry for my bad question construction. Im trying to make a programm, which would represent a TreeSet data in table with javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.
Actual problem was in AbstractTableModel's getValueAt(int r, int c) method, which needs an index for every table element. Since sets don't have an index, i decided to convert data into 2D array just for table because it makes things simple. But now i'm stuck with setValueAt(Object value,int r,int c), where i should convert edited data back to Set.
Now i'm thinking of converting this Set to List instead of array since it would be easy to transfer back.

Comment: show us what you've tried so far

Comment: And my question is: why? Java is an *object oriented language*, resolving an object list to an Array just feels wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be a:

```
public class MyClassWhithFourFields {
 String field1;
 int field2;
 Object field3;
 double field4;
}
```

Now you can declare a set with this template:

```
Set<MyClassWhithFourFields> mySet = new HashSet<MyClassWhithFourFields>();
```

In your Set are your objects, which has 4 fields.

If you want to declare a 2 dimension array, than what type should be?
- the most common parent can be, and in this case it is the Object.

So declare a function an implement it:

```
Object[][] transformSetTo2dArray(Set < MyClassWhithFourFields > mySet) {
 if (mySet == null) {
  return null;
 }
 Object[][] result = new Object[4][mySet.size()];
 int j = 0;
 // iterate the set:
 for (MyClassWhithFourFields myObject: mySet) {
  myObject[0][j] = myObject.field1;
  myObject[1][j] = myObject.field2;
  myObject[2][j] = myObject.field3;
  myObject[3][j] = myObject.field4;
  j++;
 }
 return result;
}
```